# no suitable method found for sort(List<User>)

Tags: java

This thing just won't compile. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.The compiler is barking at *Collections.sort(users);*. See the error message down below right after the program listing. It would be much appreciated if you could provide any kind of insight as to what is really wrong with that piece of code.

Here's the output from the command *java -version*:

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        users.add(new User("John Doe"));
        users.add(new User("Bob Smith"));
        users.add(new User("Jane Doe"));
        users.add(new User("Bill Gates"));

        Collections.sort(users);

        for (User user : users)
            System.out.println(user.name);
   }
}

class User implements Comparable<User> {
    public String name;
    User(String name) { this.name = name; }
    @Override public int compareTo(User user) {
        return this.name.compareTo(user.name);
    }
}
```

Here's the ugly error message that I'm getting:

```
MyApp.java:15: error: no suitable method found for sort(List<User>)
            Collections.sort(users);
                   ^
    method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: User
        upper bounds: Comparable<? super T#1>)
    method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is     not appli
cable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method     <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<?     super
 T#2>)
1 error
```

Comment: Which java version do you use?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Since you're importing ArrayList, List and Collections *but not* Comparable, and since I've seen this before: did you define you own interface called Comparable?

Comment: No, I didn't define anything. The code in the listing is all there is.

Comment: Checking for extraordinary usage: there is a MyApp.java and User.java in the same package?

Comment: No, there's only one file--MyApp.java. Everything is in the default package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code compiles fine with JDK 1.7.0.60, 1.7.0.80, 1.8.0.25 and 1.8.0.40. Probably you have some early 1.8.0.x javac which had many problems with generics. Try to update it to the latest.

Comment: java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Well, when I downloaded and installed my Java compiler, which was about 5 or 6 months ago, it was the latest version at the time. So, I don't think my compiler is that old. The generics feature has been around for much longer, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler complains about this try giving the hint about the type:

```
 Collections.<User>sort(users);
```

Comment: error: method sort in class Collections cannot be applied to give
n types;
        Collections.<User>sort(users);
                   ^
  required: List<T>
  found: List<User>
  reason: explicit type argument User does not conform to declared bound(s) Comp
arable<? super User>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable<? super T> declared in method <T>sort(List<T>)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get
full output
1 error